# Fit text to bitmap width

Tags: android, text, android-canvas

I need to draw text, that fills given Rect() horizontally (just spaces should be stretched). Is there any ways, except counting each word width ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem. In your onDraw(Canvas c) function use the following code:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  TextPaint mTextpaint = new TextPaint();
  mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  mTextPaint.setTextSize(14);
  mTextpaint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);

  final String mText = "Hello World";
  final int maxTextWidth = 40;

  DynamicLayout dl = new DynamicLayout(mText, mTextPaint, 
      maxTextWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 1.0f, false);

  canvas.translate(0, 100);
  dl.draw(canvas);
}
```

This example creates a TextLayout (DynamicLayout) which is given a maximum width, the configured TextPaint and a text. It draws on the canvas object a centered text "Hello World", for more documentation about TextLayouts you can use the Android development documentation ;)
A comment from me: the example code isnt optimized, you can setup the Textpaint in every other function, event the Text and maxTextWidth - because of sometimes heavy use of the onDraw() event this is some better to put the code in a another not often used function like the class constructor or so.

Comment: Thanks for example, but it's not exactly what i need. I want the same effect, like "text-align: justify" in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just try StaticLayout (for static text) or DynamicLayout (dynimc text) in your onDraw() function , this are text layouts you can give a maximum of width. You can use this even with TextUtils.EllipSize to cut your texts.